# jquery resize li based on a string size

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some query which will calculate the pixel width for each li.
problem is it doesnt take into consideration the amount of characters in an A href.

You might get "Cartouches/Réservoirs" and it will attempt to assign 124px width based on the calculation of the other items.

I need to check first if the number of characters will fit in the assigned size, if they dont then increase the size by remove some from an LI that has sufficient space.

```
$('div#new-menu-lower ul li').css('width', ($('div#new-menu-lower ul').width() / $('div#new-menu-lower ul li').length));
    $(function() {
        var menuWidth = $('div#new-menu-lower ul').width();
        var listItems = $('div#new-menu-lower > ul > li').length;
        var itemWidth = Math.floor(menuWidth * (1/listItems)) - 20;

    $('div#new-menu-lower ul li').css('width', itemWidth);
});
```

Here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zwqYf/3/

As you can see when you hover the items are broken.

Is there anyway to get round this?

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish, and why in this way?

Comment: because the css method bunches the li's together, i need it full width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/zwqYf/10/:

We get `li` elements.

```
var els=$('div#new-menu-lower ul li');
```

We store each `li`'s width (including borders, paddings and margins).

```
elsWidth=new Array();
for(var i=0;i<els.length;i++){
 elsWidth[i]=$(els[i]).outerWidth(true);  
}
```

We sum them into `total`

```
var total=0;
for(var i=0;i<elsWidth.length;i++){
 total+=elsWidth[i];  
}
```

Then we have an `ul` of `960px` which must contain at least `total` px.

Then, the available space is `$('div#new-menu-lower ul').width()-total`.

So each `li` can have an extra width of `($('div#new-menu-lower ul').width()-total)/(els.length)`.

```
var availWidthForEl=($('div#new-menu-lower ul').width()-total)/(els.length);
```

We round it to 2 decimals

```
availWidthForEl=Math.floor(availWidthForEl*100)/100;
```

Finally we assign to each `li` its current with (without borders, paddings and margins) plus its extra width:

```
for(var i=0;i<els.length;i++){
 $(els[i]).css('width', $(els[i]).width()+availWidthForEl);
}
```

Comment: oh wow... can i have some comments in the code so i know whats going on please? bit of a noob! sorry

Answer (score 2):

I can see what you are trying to do, but there are ways far easier to do what you need, without even the need for javascript/jquery.

Consider this:

http://jsfiddle.net/zwqYf/4/

- removed inline width styling.
- changed position:relative and top:3 to line-height
- changed li's padding for "unbunching"

If you need to make them more apart, change the padding on the li's.

If you need to change the button's height, don't forget to change the a's line-height too.

**EDIT:**

http://jsfiddle.net/zwqYf/5/ - updated, removed some redundant css, made padding between li's larger.

Comment: Thats kinda what i mean yes, but the li's need to stretch to the full width of the UL. When you hover on the last li there shouldnt be any background from the UL showing.

Comment: what do you  mean stretch to full width? You want the button to take up the entire width of the menu??

Comment: almost as if i need some sort of `min-padding-right` thats CSS3 right?

Comment: Im sorry I just do not understand what you want the final product to look like.

Comment: @Matt Hintzke: Look at how i have hovered on the last item but there is still space on the right. The padding needs to be fluid so it fills that space. http://i47.tinypic.com/2pt7a5w.png

Comment: so you want the li to be fluid and all have different width's based on the amount of text in the li? But make it so the menu spans across the entire width of the ul (960px)?